# Can I use a corner bead over wood?

Tags: carpentry, joints, corner-bead

So for context, I had a stack pipe replaced, then I had a carpenter come and build a new wooden enclosure (see pictures) to cover the stack and the other pipes bringing water to an upstairs bathroom. The left side of the enclosure the carpenter built leaves a small gap between the original wooden enclosure, and the new one (the gap is prominent in the last picture in particular). I'm considering using a paper-facing corner bead, a layer of joint compound, and some texture in a can to get a nice corner on the left side that blends into the original paint. I'm having a hard time finding information about using one over a wood surface. So, can I use a paper-facing corner bead in this situation? If not, what should I do instead to finish this corner? Thanks[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]